# Teamviewer computers and contacts

Tags: teamviewer

How do I get the computers and contacts window to close with the main window in teamviewer 11. Normally in older versions when I would close the main window the computers and contacts window would close. Now I have to close them individually.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I found that when I click and drag the Computers and Contacts window next to the main Tewamviewer window until it "snaps" onto it, they become synced and closing one will close both. Hope this helps.